# tcpdump time based circular rotation

Tags: tcpdump

Despite reading the man page and searching StackExchange and the wider internet, I have failed to figure out a way to make a time based, rotating, limited count, tcpdump.

I want for example to have one file per hour, with no more than 24 hours. But I don't want tcpdump to stop after 24 files, I want it to delete the oldest and create a new file. I want it to run forever but never make more than 24 files.

The man page seems to indicate that if you use `-C -W -G` together you can achieve this, but my testing has not shown this to work.

Using `-G -W` and a `strftime` exits after 5 files

```
# tcpdump -w foo.%F_%H%M%S -G 5 -W 5 -Z root port 22
tcpdump: listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
Maximum file limit reached: 5
```

Using all three together seems to just limit the number of files generated per timeframe. For example the below will capture up to 5 x 1MB files in each 5s window. If there is more than 5MB in 5s, only the last 5MB are kept. The number of total files though, will grow forever.

```
# tcpdump -w foo.%F_%H%M%S -G 5 -C 1 -W 5 -Z root port 22
```

This will capture 5 x 1MB files and overwrite in a ring.

```
# tcpdump -w foo -C 1 -W 5 -Z root port 22
```

But I want to rotate by time, not size.

Comment: Use `-G` alone, and delete old files from `cron`.

Comment: Or write a command to delete the 25th file (eg from `ls|tail -n +24`) and call the command from `-z`. Make sure you ignore the filename passed in.

Comment: So there is no way in just tcpdump to do what I want? There are lots of ways to skin the cat using multiple tools/scripts together, I was just hoping for an all in one option.

Comment: Well, UNIX is about doing one thing well. Although in this particular case it seems to be bad design more than anything. A better design would have been for `tcpdump` to respond to something like `SIGHUP` or `SIGUSR1` by closing the current file and opening it anew. That would have played well with log rotators such as `newsyslog`. Or just make `-C` and `-W` apply regardless to handle rotation itself, as you say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take the following as an example that produces six capture files per minute indefinitely:

`# tcpdump -i eth0 -G 10 -w dump-%S.pcap`.

Note that only the second time variable `%S` needs to be specified in the template file name, with a rotational time frame of ten seconds specified by `-G`. When the capture time changes from minute to minute, `tcpdump` overwrites the previous second-marked file.

Now, a hourly rotational and daily cyclical capture could be achieved by:

`# tcpdump -i eth0 -G 3600 -w dump-%H.pcap`.

The same rationale applies here. `tcpdump` creates a new file every 3600 seconds, naming it with the current hour. Upon changing days, the previous hour files are sequentially replaced.